# Run As shortcut does not work but right click approach does

Tags: windows-7, shortcuts, runas

I currently have Battlefield installed. Since it does not support save slots, I created another local user account for my brother with administrative rights. Then, I ran the game using Shift+Right click >> Run as different user. This works perfectly.

However, to avoid typing the creds everytime, I used the tutorial - [Run as Different User Shortcut - Create for Specified Program and User](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/164915-run-different-user-shortcut-create-specified-program-user.html) to create a shortcut with my brother's account. This method, however, launches the EXE and then closes it. The same does not occur when using the right click approach.

What am I doing wrong?

The command that I am using in the shortcut is as below:

```
runas /savecred /user:"<UserName>" "D:\Games\Battlefield Hardline\bfh.exe"
```

Comment: Do a google search to RunAdmin on Soft.Tahionic.com. Does exactly what you want.