# How to run batch file command with elevated permissions?

Tags: windows, command-line, permissions, batch-file

I am writing a batch file that I will distribute among users. I need to run some commands with elevated permissions. My initial solution was to use:

```
runas /noprofile /user:Administrator SOME_COMMAND
```

However many machines (including mine) have the hidden Administrator account inactive and so do not have an administrator password set up. I can also not specify another user name since different machines will have different users. Is there a way to replicate the "right click -> Run as Administrator" action via a batch file? I do not mind the prompt popping up, I just do not want the user to explicitly right-click and run as administrator.

Comment: See if this answers your question and if so feel free to give it an upvote!!... http://superuser.com/questions/1082071/run-as-shortcut-does-not-work-but-right-click-approach-does/1082083#1082083

Comment: [How can I auto-elevate my batch file, so that it requests from UAC administrator rights if required?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7044985/how-can-i-auto-elevate-my-batch-file-so-that-it-requests-from-uac-administrator)

Comment: @w32sh Thanks, however the accepted answer requires that an additional application be installed which takes away from the portability that I want in my file.

Comment: No external applications required. Pls check out this particular post. http://stackoverflow.com/a/12264592

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can take advantage of PowerShell, which is present on every modern Windows system.

Split the commands that need elevation off into a separate batch file, e.g. `elevated.bat`. Then, when it's time to run them, use this from your non-elevated script:

```
powershell -command "Start-Process elevated.bat -Verb runas"
```

The `-Verb runas` part is what causes the elevation prompt. If the original batch file is already running as admin, or if UAC prompts are off, the new file will be elevated without a prompt.

Note that the elevated batch processor's current directory will start out as `System32`. If that's a problem, you can use this alternate version to have it start in the same directory as the non-elevated script:

```
powershell -command "Start-Process cmd -ArgumentList '/c cd /d %CD% && elevated.bat' -Verb runas"
```

That causes the new `cmd` instance to first `cd` into the directory provided by the unelevated prompt's `%CD%` variable, then execute the desired batch file.

Comment: Thanks. However powershell scripts are disabled by default on almost all machines. `Right click->run as Admin` on batch files would be more convenient in that case than first having users enable powershell scripts.

Comment: @hazrmard This doesn't require script execution to be enabled, since you're just running a command, not a script file. (I just checked and `-command` can indeed be used even if scripts can't.)

Comment: True. But I am distributing a batch file among users. Which means I'll have to ask users to first type in this command in power shell to run the batch file. I don't even trust my users to `Right click-> Run as admin`. Hence my question in the first place :)

Comment: @hazrmard You're not running a PowerShell command, you're invoking `powershell.exe` from your batch script to automatically run one PS command. The user will never even know PowerShell is involved.

Comment: Splendid. Works for cmd itself as well: `powershell -command "Start-Process cmd.exe -Verb runas"`

Comment: In the second variant (for switching to the current working directory) the argument list option must be `-ArgumentList '/c cd /D %CD% && elevated.bat'`. The `cd /D` is missing in the original post. The `/D` option is only necessary, if you switch to another drive (other than `C:`). [The `/C` option to `cmd` before](https://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html) is not for switching the working directory, but for setting `cmd` to close after executing the command.

Comment: I tried the simple version, just invoking my .bat directly without the `cmd` or `cd`, and even when I use -Verb runAs my working directory is _not_ changed to System32; my batch script has the same working directory as I have when I invoke powershell... ??

Comment: @Neonit Fixed now, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

[RunAdmin](http://www.soft.tahionic.com/download-run%20as%20admin%20console%20command/index.html) lets you run a program from command line with elevated rights (it will show the UAC so the user can enter credentials).

Answer (score 1):

Continuing on the answer by Ben N:

To make a batch script self-elevating (automatically restart as administrator if started unelevated) you can use the following code first in the script (here I am using `FSUTIL DIRTY query` to test for admin rights).

```
FSUTIL DIRTY query %SystemDrive% >NUL || (
    PowerShell "Start-Process -FilePath '%0' -Verb RunAs"
    EXIT
)

REM Main code here
```

alternatively, if your script requires the working directory to be the same as the batch file location, use:

```
FSUTIL DIRTY query %SystemDrive% >NUL || (
    PowerShell "Start-Process -FilePath cmd.exe -Args '/C CHDIR /D %CD% & "%0"' -Verb RunAs"
    EXIT
)

REM Main code here
```

Comment: it workded fine

Answer (score 0):

What I use is the following code:

```
::#################################################################################################################################
:: Elevate this script                                                                                                            #
::#################################################################################################################################

(
    :: Check Admin rights and create VBS Script to elevate
    >nul fsutil dirty query %SYSTEMDRIVE% 2>&1 || (

        :: Very little red console
        mode con cols=80 lines=3 
        color cf

        :: Message
        title Please wait...
        echo.
        echo                         Requesting elevated shell...

        :: Create VBS script
        echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^)>"%TEMP%\elevate.vbs"
        echo UAC.ShellExecute "%~f0", "%TEMP%\elevate.vbs", "", "runas", 1 >>"%TEMP%\elevate.vbs"
        if exist "%TEMP%\elevate.vbs" start /b /wait >nul cscript /nologo "%TEMP%\elevate.vbs" 2>&1

        :: Delete elevation script if exist
        if exist "%TEMP%\elevate.vbs" >nul del /f "%TEMP%\elevate.vbs" 2>&1

        exit /b
    )    
)

pushd "%~dp0"

.... your code ....

popd
```

Put it after your @echo off and remarks.

Comment: See https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-elevate.html for an improved admin check test (Win10 requires drive letter)

Comment: Thanks. Currently on w7. Didn't yet test it on w10.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry for very bad english.
This will be run batch file as elevated (with admin privileged)
This script is created by Matt (https://stackoverflow.com/users/1016343/matt)
And i modified the Matt script.
Update: Added windows system folder checker.
Script:

```
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:: Elevate.cmd - Version 4
:: Automatically check & get admin rights
:: see "https://stackoverflow.com/a/12264592/1016343" for description
:: Sorry for very bad english
:: Modified script. Added check windows
:: system folder and then add it to ENV
:: (Envronment Variable)
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
 @echo off
 CLS
 ECHO.
 ECHO =============================
 ECHO Running Admin shell
 ECHO =============================

:init
 setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
 set cmdInvoke=1
 
:checkWinSys
 set "ResultFile=%temp%\checkSysResult.txt"
 if exist "%SystemRoot%\Sysnative" (
 echo 1
 goto checkSysResult
 ) > "%ResultFile%"

 if exist "%SystemRoot%\System32" (
 echo 2
 goto checkSysResult
 ) > "%ResultFile%"

 setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

 set count=0

 for /f "tokens=*" %%x in (%ResultFile%) do (
     set /a count+=1
     set var[!count!]=%%x
 )

:checkSysResult
 if "%var[3]%"=="1" ( set winSysFolder=Sysnative & goto skip ) else ( set winSysFolder=System32 & goto skip )

:skip
 del "%ResultFile%"
 setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion

:init(1)
 set "batchPath=%~0"
 for %%k in (%0) do set batchName=%%~nk
 set "vbsGetPrivileges=OEgetPriv_%batchName%.vbs"
 setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

:checkPrivileges
  NET FILE 1>NUL 2>NUL
  if '%errorlevel%' == '0' ( goto gotPrivileges ) else ( goto getPrivileges )

:getPrivileges
  if '%1'=='ELEV' (echo ELEV & shift /1 & goto gotPrivileges)
  ECHO.
  ECHO **************************************
  ECHO Invoking UAC for Privilege Escalation
  ECHO **************************************

  ECHO Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%vbsGetPrivileges%"
  ECHO args = "ELEV " >> "%vbsGetPrivileges%"
  ECHO For Each strArg in WScript.Arguments >> "%vbsGetPrivileges%"
  ECHO args = args ^& strArg ^& " "  >> "%vbsGetPrivileges%"
  ECHO Next >> "%vbsGetPrivileges%"

  if '%cmdInvoke%'=='1' goto InvokeCmd 

  ECHO UAC.ShellExecute "!batchPath!", args, "", "runas", 1 >> "%vbsGetPrivileges%"
  goto ExecElevation

:InvokeCmd
  ECHO args = "/c """ + "!batchPath!" + """ " + args >> "%vbsGetPrivileges%"
  ECHO UAC.ShellExecute "%SystemRoot%\%winSysFolder%\cmd.exe", args, "", "runas", 1 >> "%vbsGetPrivileges%"

:ExecElevation
 "%SystemRoot%\%winSysFolder%\WScript.exe" "%vbsGetPrivileges%" %*
 exit /B

:gotPrivileges
 setlocal & pushd .
 cd /d %~dp0
 if '%1'=='ELEV' (del "%vbsGetPrivileges%" 1>nul 2>nul  &  shift /1)

 ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
 ::START
 ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
 REM Run shell as admin (example) - put here code as you like
 ECHO %batchName% Arguments: P1=%1 P2=%2 P3=%3 P4=%4 P5=%5 P6=%6 P7=%7 P8=%8 P9=%9
 cmd /k
```

Comment: dont run this code.it delete my entire code inside the folder