# Batch file with elevated permissions is not working?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, batch, cmd.exe, uac

After seeing this solution:
[How to run batch file command with elevated permissions?](https://superuser.com/questions/1110448/how-to-run-batch-file-command-with-elevated-permissions)

I put this in a batch file:

```
powershell -command "Start-Process cmd -ArgumentList '/c %CD% && elevated.bat' -Verb runas"
```

Next to that file, I put "elevated.bat" with this command:

```
regedit /S reg_entries.reg
```

After doing that, it pops up a UAC prompt for Windows Command Processor aka cmd.exe:

UAC dialog box for cmd:

[image]

I'm definitely logged in as an administrator (confirmed by checking in Control Panel > User Accounts)

I am stuck now!

I thought the aim of the first command above was to stop this UAC prompt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Did you check the special permission box?
If not, right click on command prompt and then go to security, press the edit button and check the special permissions label on the allow side

Hope that helps.

Comment: This was for an "attended" Windows setup. I since swapped to unattended for other reasons and the prompt never comes up, it's strange since both my attended and unattended run the same batch file at the same point, but one pops up the box, the other doesn't. I'll just mark your answer as accepted because, it would work (were I not in Windows setup with explorer killed at the time :p)